# Getting number of current viewers for a UStream video using the REST API?

Tags: http, rest

Whenever you view a UStream video there is a little counter at the bottom of the screen that tells you how many users are currently viewing the video and how many have viewed it in total.  I would like to get the current # of viewers using the REST API, but thus far have only figured out how to get the number of total views, I have tried a bunch of different queries(the lack of documentation on UStreams end isnt helping) but thus far have not figured this one out.  What property/query do I need to get the current # of viewers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, with some thanks to [the blizztv project](http://code.google.com/p/blizztv/), you have to use the listAllChannels(which gets all the channels owned by the user who created the channel in question) command to get the info, because its oddly absent from the getInfo command....

Anyway, your request is going to look something like this:

```
http://api.ustream.tv/json/channel/(channel #)/listAllChannels?key=yourkey
```